# If else statement printing "you're right" even if the minimum length is not met

Tags: python, if-statement

I just started python and I'm having some trouble using the if else statement in python. I'm trying to create a program that checks the length of a password. If it matches the minimum length it should print a message saying you're correct, but when it doesn't it should print you're not correct. When I run my code, it only prints out "you're correct" even though the min length is not met. I'm not sure if I have used the if else statement correctly, do I need to use 2 variables to make it work?

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6 #The length of the password is determined by the variable MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH.
                    #We have assigned the variable with the value of 6.

password = input('Enter your password: ')
password_length = len(password)

if MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH >= 6:
    print("Your password is correct!")
else:
    print("Your not correct!")

print('Number of characters used in password: ', password_length,'and the min length expected is: ',MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
```

Comment: you're using `MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH` not  `password_length` in your if statement, so it will always test `6 >= 6`. You meant to do `if password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing your constant variable, you should use:

```
if password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[image] The problem was in your if condition. It seems you meant to check if `password_lenth` was equal or greater than `MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH` , instead you were checking if `MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH >= 6` which is checking if MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH was greater than 6.

You can fix it by replacing `if MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH >= 6:` with this line:

```
if password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
```

Hope its the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The if statement should be

```
if password_length >= MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
```